# Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io...i/o timeout

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ubuntu-18.04, minikube

I was trying to pull an image from docker.io, but I'm getting this error, recently I have changed my DNS I'm not sure is that the reason...I executed `minikube ssh` and I executed `docker pull` then I got this error

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:32905->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout
```

My Env -:
   Docker version -: 19.03.1
   minikube version -: 1.2.0
   ubuntu version -: 18.04

This is my resolv.conf.d --> head file content

nameserver 192.xxx.1x8.x

Comment: Are you behind any proxy that might block the connection?

Comment: I was able to fix this by changing my DNS to 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 5):

I was working on a side project and at some point needed to run a new docker image `docker pull nginx` that wasn't on my machine. When I tried to run it I got this error:

> Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.0.1:53: read udp 10.0.0.30:55526->10.0.0.1:53: i/o timeout.

I was surprised to see that, but I managed to find quick solution for this:

- Edit your DNS resolver config file: `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`
- Change or add nameserver `8.8.8.8` at the end of the file and you're good to go.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this by changing the DNS to 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 1):

This is normally indicating that, you have error with your internet connection. Whenever i have above issue, i just disconnect from my network and reconnect, and most of the time it works.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnected from my wifi and connected again, it worked

Comment: add brief comments

Comment: I tried but not working...

Answer (score 0):

I just add `8.8.8.8` into `resolv.conf` and run:

```
service networking restart
```

And this fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your network uses VPN then that might be the issue. Modify your 'resolve.conf' file in 'etc' folder of ubuntu with the VPN DNS server address. It worked for me