# Skaffold dev fails

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, minikube, skaffold

I am having this error, after running **skaffold dev**.

```
Step 1/6 : FROM node:current-alpine3.11
exiting dev mode because first build failed: unable to stream build output: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.49.1:53: read udp 192.168.49.2:35889->192.168.49.1:53: i/o timeout. Please fix the Dockerfile and try again..
```

Here is skaffold.yml

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta11
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: *****
build:
  artifacts:
    - image: 127.0.0.1:32000/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - infra/k8s/auth-depl.yaml
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: 127.0.0.1:32000/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: "src/**/*.ts"
            dest: .
```

I have tried all possible solutions I saw online, including adding 8.8.8.8 as the DNS, but the error still persists. I am using Linux and running ubuntu, I am also using Minikube locally. Please assist.

Comment: Could you try node:current-buster and see if you get the same error?

Comment: I get the same error with node:current-buster

Comment: This looks like more of a Dockerfile issue than Skaffold itself, are you able to build an image with that Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes I can build an image with the Dockerfile

Comment: Did you try to restart docker daemon ?

Comment: When using Minikube, Skaffold will build using Minikube's Docker daemon, not your local daemon. You can try `(eval $(minikube docker-env); docker build ...)` to perform the build using the Minikube's docker daemon.  Stepping back: has `skaffold dev` ever worked for you in this situation, or is this a new behaviour change?  (If it worked previously, does a `minikube delete; minikube start` solve the problem?).  Do you have custom firewall rules?

Comment: Yes, minikube delete; minikube start solved the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is a Community Wiki answer, posted for better visibility, so feel free to edit it and add any additional details you consider important.*

In this case:

```
minikube delete && minikube start
```

solved the problem but you can start from restarting **docker daemon**. Since this is **Minikube** cluster and **Skaffold** uses for its builds **Minikube's Docker daemon**, as suggested by [Brian de Alwis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/600339/brian-de-alwis) in his comment, you may start from:

```
minikube stop && minikube start
```

or

```
minikube ssh
su
systemctl restart docker
```

I searched for similar errors and in many cases e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61114031) or [in this thread](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1317), setting up your DNS to something reliable like `8.8.8.8` may also help:

```
sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

in case you use **Minikube** you should first:

```
minikube ssh

su ### to become root
```

and then run:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

The following error message:

```
Please fix the Dockerfile and try again
```

may be somewhat misleading in similar cases as `Dockerfile` is probably totally fine, but as we can read in other part:

```
lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.49.1:53: read udp 192.168.49.2:35889->192.168.49.1:53: i/o timeout.
```

it's definitely related with failing DNS lookup. This is well described [here](http://docs.docker.oeynet.com/docker-cloud/docker-errors-faq/) as well known issue.

> ### Get i/o timeout
>
> *Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories//images: dial tcp: lookup  on :53: read udp :53: i/o timeout*
>
> #### Description
>
> The DNS resolver configured on the host cannot resolve the registry’s
> hostname.
>
> #### GitHub link
>
> N/A
>
> #### Workaround
>
> Retry the operation, or if the error persists, use another DNS
> resolver. You can do this by updating your  `/etc/resolv.conf`  file
> with these or other DNS servers:
>
> `nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4`